# CDI producer benefit

Tags: java, cdi

I'm trying to convert jsf2 application from `managed beans` to `CDI`.

So I'm learning and discovering the advantages of `CDI`. It seems great but there is something I don't understand with `producer`.

About `CDI` I read that one of the advantages is to reduce `coupling`.  I did some experimentation with an interface, some implementation, the `@default`, `@alternate`, `@inject`. And it's doing the job.  In that case I can see the coupling 'reduction'.

But when implementing a producer for logging, I don't see it.

For now I'm using something like

```
Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

With CDI, after creating the producer, I have

```
@Inject
Logger logger;
```

Ok, it's shorter but the Logger class is still coupled with e.g. log4j.

So if I want to use another logger library I'll still have to modify all my classes.

Is there something I didn't understand ?

Answer (score 2):

You're idea is not bad, and it can indeed helps to abstract which logger you use.
However, you may need to use a logging adapter such as slf4j (https://www.slf4j.org/) or commons-logging, that will help you to choose between different loggers implementations (log4j,etc.) but keeping the same logging interface.

You then keep a single producer method in CDI that can be customize at will.